# How to hide a single header file from gcc

Tags: gcc, g++, include

I am compiling a c++ project and trying to find all what all functions from `ncurses.h` are used throughout the project.
I was wondering if I can tell gcc to not include specifically `ncurses.h`?

Comment: Instead of hiding the header file, why not leave out the ncurses lib-file when linking? It should show you exactly what functions are missing.

Comment: Yes, but I was interested in locations in the project where they are used. Sorry I failed to mention that. :)

Comment: If building with debug information, then the linker error message shows you exactly where a missing function was used.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up passing `-D__NCURSES_H=1` on command line. ‍♂️